# Fixing encodings

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mojibake

I have ended up with messed up character encodings in one of our mysql columns.

Typically I have

√© instead of é
√∂ instead of ö
√≠ instead of í

and so on...

Fairly certain that someone here would know what happened and how to fix.

**UPDATE:**
Based on bobince's answer and since I had this data in a file I did the following

```
#!/user/bin/env python
import codecs
f = codecs.open('./file.csv', 'r', 'utf-8')
f2 = codecs.open('./file-fixed.csv', 'w', 'utf-8')
for line in f:
    f2.write(line.encode('macroman').decode('utf-8')),
```

after which

```
load data infile 'file-fixed.csv' 
into table list1 
fields terminated by ',' 
optionally enclosed by '"' 
ignore 1 lines;
```

properly imported the data.

**UPDATE2:**
Hammerite, just for completeness here are the requested details...

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_connection | latin1                     | 
| character_set_database   | latin1                     | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | latin1                     | 
| character_set_server     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table I am importing to has `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

**EDIT3:**

Actually with the above settings the `load` **didn't** do the right thing (I could not compare to existing utf8 fields and my loaded data only *looked* as if it was loaded correctly; I assume because of the *wrong, but matching* client, connection and results charsets), so I updated the settings to:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_connection | utf8                       | 
| character_set_database   | utf8                       | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | utf8                       | 
| character_set_server     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

uploaded data again and then finally I got the data loaded correctly (comparable with existing data).

Comment: What encoding is it currently using? How is data being inserted?

Comment: Echoing NullUserException, please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE TableName`. Please also post the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'`.

Comment: @Hammerite, NullUserException, thanks for your input...

Comment: Glad you sorted out your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your text has been encoded to UTF-8 and then re-decoded, erroneously, as [Mac Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman).

You won't be able to fix this inside the database, as MySQL doesn't know the Mac Roman encoding. You might write a script to walk each row of each affected table and fix up the text by reversing the encode/decode cycle. Python is a possibility, having a good range of encodings:

```
>>> print u'√©'.encode('macroman').decode('utf-8')
é
>>> print u'√∂'.encode('macroman').decode('utf-8')
ö
>>> print u'√≠'.encode('macroman').decode('utf-8')
í
```

Alternatively, if there is no non-ASCII content that is unaffected by this problem, you could try using `mysqladmin` to export an SQL dump, then convert it all at once, either using a script as above or, if you have a text editor (presumably on the Mac) that can do it, loading the script as UTF-8 then saving it as Mac Roman. Finally re-import the dump using `mysql < dump.sql`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir... I'll update the question with the solution; I had the data in the file actually