# SQL Function to Replace Microsoft Characters (especially "smart quotes") with UTF-8 compatible characters

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, utf-8

I have a server running MySQL (tomcat, java spring) and recently upgraded the entire database to utf8mb4.

However, I'm now noticing characters we've likely copied from Word are causing issues - like "smart quotes" in the data are showing as `â€™` in the app's UI. Similar issue seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854482/mysql-turns-into-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC).

Is there a function I can create in MySQL to just replace these Windows 1252-specific characters with UTF-8 equivalents moving forward? Or another solution to do this dynamically?

The goal is to avoid the issue for all users who try to save information copied from MS Word and other similar sources in the future. Such data may come from editing in the UI, bulk imports, etc. so I'd like the adjustment in the back-end to apply to all of these use cases where data is inserted into the db.

--

To fix the immediate issue, I was able to run a couple of queries to change the left and right smart quotes similar to this: ([source](https://topher1kenobe.com/microsoft-smart-quotes-in-mysql/))

```
UPDATE artist SET artist_blurb = REPLACE(artist_blurb, ”’, ”’)
    WHERE artist_blurb LIKE ‘%’%’;

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'; result is: | Variable_name | Value |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+ 
| character_set_client | utf8 | 
| character_set_connection | utf8 | 
| character_set_database | utf8mb4 | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary | 
| character_set_results | utf8 | 
| character_set_server | latin1 | 
| character_set_system | utf8 |
```

Comment: `â€™` is Mojibake.  How did you "convert" the database?  Perhaps the wrong way.  Please provide the queries used for such, plus `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And do `SELECT HEX(col) ...` so we can see what is currently stored.

Comment: â€™ does not show in the database. The " is what shows in the database itself. Everything was converted properly via dropping and recreating. The problem is that smart quote symbol is from Microsoft and not UTF-8.

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'; result is:
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |

Comment: Use hex() to see what is really in the column.

Comment: HEX for left quote: E2809C & for right quote: E2809D

Comment: If you are seeing hex E2809C` in the table, but jibberish when displayed, then you have "Mojibake"; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Thanks Rick. I've done everything listed there as solutions so I'm thinking the answer to my original question - if this can be prevented when copying text from tools like Word into the db - is "no".

Comment: It should be possible to copy and paste.  But there may be about 5 places where utf8 must be configured.  Probably only 1 is incorrectly set now.