# MySQL - Russian characters display incorectly

Tags: mysql, encoding, cyrillic

I have to make an russian version of a website, but I can't find out, how to insert russian characters into Database.

I tryed almost every possible coding, but it only shows:

```
???????? ?????????? ??????? ??????? ? ????? ?? ????????????? ? ???????, ??????? ????? ??????? ???????? ????? .??? ??????????? ???????? ????? ?? ????? ?????????? ? ????? ????????.
??????????? ?????? ?? ???????? ????? ?? 20 ???????. ???????? ??? ?? ??????????? ?????????????? ????? ? ????????????? ??????? ??????. ? ???????, ? ??????? ? ?.?.
```

Comment: what is encoding used for the database? and where you are trying to display?

Comment: Where is your output from? The data passes through various layers. Here is a link to similar questions so you can see the various parameters that mysql is influenced with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823278/fixing-encondings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Make sure the database charset/collation is UTF-8
2. On the page you insert these russian characters ( the form, textarea ), make sure the encoding is UTF-8, by setting Content-Type to `text/html; charset=utf-8`. Enter in russian text directly to the form input.
3. On the processing page that handles this form, which inserts it into the database, make sure to do `SET NAMES utf8` so it's stored as UTF-8 **before** you insert the data, in a separate query beforehand.
4. When you render the content from the database in a view, make sure the `Content-Type` is `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Make sure that the content-type is **not** windows-1251 or iso-8859-1/latin1. Make sure the database charset/collation is NOT ISO-8859-1/Latin1.

Comment: Ok, the important phrase of your reply way "make sure" .. :-) I had UTF-8 on the DB and the Tables, but what I found out, that I had fixed encoding to latin2 on the Columns. Thanks. :-)

Comment: You surely mean "collation", not "coallition"

Answer (score 4):

For storing russian characters in db your db should support UTF-8 encoding.
Modify your table with below query to enable UTF-8 encoding.

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your database table is set to UTF-8 encoding. You can run the following SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Make sure that your database connection also uses UTF-8 encoding:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
```

Make sure that your HTML form is configured to use UTF-8 encoding:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```