# Inserting Russian characters become question marks (????? ?????? ?)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, rds

I am trying to insert russian characters as well as other languages into a table, After insertion all i see is question marks instead of the russian text.

I am using Amazon rds and have tried these commands from my MySql work bench but it did not work, after inserting again it is question marks

```
SET character_set_client = utf8;
SET character_set_results = utf8;
SET character_set_connection = utf8;
```

I am inserting and selecting from MySql workbench. java html and php are not involved

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Russian characters display incorectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316290/mysql-russian-characters-display-incorectly)

Comment: these kind of problems are like the worst you can encounter...

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to sort this annoying issue by adding the following to my connection string

```
&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: this issue also happens to me when I use [SQL Workbench/J](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/) and [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/index.html) and this is the fix!

Comment: in case anyone is wondering how to pass these extra params through SQL Workbench/J -- you can do this via the "Extended Properties" button . more info see here: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/profiles.html#profile-extended-properties. Pass in the above extra params as key-value in the Extended Properties and the solution works like a charm!