# When i'm sending a request from JSP to MySQL, in DB showes not correct Russian symbols

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

I have got a problem when i'm trying to send russian symbols from JSP to MySQL. After INSERT request it showes me something like in a pic(in name, surname field). But when i'm adding russian symbols streight to the database it showes normal. I tryed everything! Nothing helps.
[image]

This is my JSP page

```
    <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<fmt:requestEncoding value="utf-8"/>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link
    href="<c:url value="/resources/registration/css/registration.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/login/inputs/demo.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/registration/inputs/set2.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/registration/css/fontsReg.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/registration/css/buttonsReg.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/login/inputs/normalize.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="bgrReg">
<div id="header">
    <img src="<c:url value="/resources/logo/logo.png"/>"/>
</div>
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
    <h5>(все поля обязательны к заполнению)</h5>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="right_block">
            <a href="login"><button class="slide_from_left">Назад</button></a>

        </div>
        <div id="left_block">

            <c:url var="saveUrl" value="registration" />
            <%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
%>
            <form:form modelAttribute="users" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}"
                class="formular">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="username" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-32" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-32">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Логин</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="password" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="password" id="input-33" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-33">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Пароль</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="name" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Имя</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="surname" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Фамилия</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="email" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Email</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:select
                                    class="selectStyle" path="gender">
                                <form:option value="Мужской"></form:option> 
                                    <form:option value="Женский"></form:option>
                                </form:select></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="age" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Возраст</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="weight" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Вес</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="height" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Рост</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"> <form:input
                                    path="sport" class="input__field input__field--manami"
                                    type="text" id="input-34" /> <label
                                class="input__label input__label--manami" for="input-34">
                                    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--manami">Спортивные
                                        навыки</span>
                            </label>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami"><form:select
                                    path="place">
                                    <form:option value="Дзержинский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Киевский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Комминтерновский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Лененский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Московский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Октябрский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Орджоникидзевский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Фрунзенский"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Холодная гора"></form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Червонозаводской"></form:option>
                                </form:select></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="input input--manami">
                                <button class="slide_from_left" type="submit">Регистрация</button>
                                <!-- <input type="submit"
                        value="<spring:message text="Регистрация"/>" /> -->
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <form:input path="enabled" type="hidden" value="true" />
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_social_db?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.vandh.app.models.Users"/>
      <mapping class="com.vandh.app.models.UserRole"/>
     <mapping class="com.vandh.app.models.Feedback"/>



      <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this is my web.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name><!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param><!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
      <filter> 
  <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name> 
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> 
  <init-param> 
  <param-name>encoding</param-name> 
  <param-value>UTF-8</param-value> 
  </init-param> 
  <init-param> 
  <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name> 
  <param-value>true</param-value> 
  </init-param> 
  </filter> 
</web-app>
```

Help me pls! I don't know what to do! I have got no ideas!!! :(

Comment: Please do `SELECT col, hex(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...;` to see what the hex is like.  Cyrillic in utf8 is encoded D0yy-D4yy and EA99yy-EA9Ayy, but perhaps only D0yy is in common use.  For example HEX('АБВГ') = 'D090D091D092D093' in utf8.  Output like 'ÐÐ‘Ð’Ð“' is "Mojibake".

Comment: @RickJames, thanx for an answer! i done your query and hex like : 'C390C2BEC3913FC390C2BBC390C2BEC390C2BF'

Answer (score 1):

Check the charset you are using it should be UTF-8.
See this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316290/mysql-russian-characters-display-incorectly) for detail answer.

Comment: thanx for an answer but it didnt help.