# SQL text file to russian string

Tags: mysql

I have sql table, where there is a field

```
first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT
```

And i have "'Р˜РіРѕСЂСЊ'", who can help to convert to readable text?

Comment: Execute: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`, add outputs to the question.

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316290/mysql-russian-characters-display-incorectly

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change collation of your table The collation effects to string comparing/sorting only. to `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`.

[Default SQL Collation depends on Language](https://www.customed.de/docs/display/CD4/Default+SQL+Collation+depends+on+Language)

Comment: *You may need to change collation of your table* The collation effects to string comparing/sorting only. *to `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`.* This collation can be not available due to charset setting.