# How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I have my database properly set to UTF-8 and am dealing with a database containing Japanese characters.  If I do SELECT *... from the mysql command line, I properly see the Japanese characters.  When pulling data out of the database and displaying it on a webpage, I see it properly.

However, when viewing the table data in phpMyAdmin, I just see garbage text.  ie.

ç§ã¯æ—¥æœ¬æ–™ç†ãŒå¥½ãã§ã™ã€‚æ—¥æœ¬æ–™ç†ã‚...

How can I get phpMyAdmin to display the characters in Japanese?

The character encoding on the HTML page is set to UTF-8.

Edit:

I have tried an export of my database and opened up the .sql file in geany.  The characters are still garbled even though the encoding is set to UTF-8.  (However, doing a mysqldump of the database also shows garbled characters).

The character set is set correctly for the database and all tables ('latin' is not found anywhere in the file)

```
CREATE DATABASE `japanese` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I have added the lines to my.cnf and restarted mysql but there is no change.  I am using Zend Framework to insert data into the database.

I am going to open a bounty for this question as I really want to figure this out.

Comment: This is probably a problem in PhpMYAdmin's connection settings. It must be explicitly set to UTF-8 as well. I don't have a copy handy but it usually is somewhere near the front page

Comment: I don't see the settings anywhere in phpMyAdmin and Google searches have come up empty handed about the settings so far.

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin are you using?

The landing page of phpMyAdmin displays the MySQL connection collation and also the MySQL charset - are both of them UTF-8?

Comment: phpMyAdmin version 3.3.2deb1 - MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) - MySQL connection collation defaults to utf8_general_ci

Comment: I hope this article could give you a good help: https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did a little more googling and came across [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305102018/http://blog.mikezhang.com/2007/03/30/phpmyadmin-display-utf8) page

The command doesn't seem to make sense but I tried it anyway:

In the file /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/mysqli.dbi.lib.php at the end of function `PMA_DBI_connect()` just before the `return` statement I added:

```
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =latin1;");
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =latin1;");
```

And it works!  I now see Japanese characters in phpMyAdmin.  WTF?  Why does this work?

Comment: This worked for me too. Did you find out why? I've checked and double checked every possible thing (all PHP / mb_string, MySQL connections / Apache / html headers / meta types) is correct set to UTF-8 and the data is stored correctly

Comment: No, I'm still not sure. I'm assuming there is a bug somewhere else in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: In my case PMA was right and the error is due to me not explicitly setting my database connection from PHP. In MY scripts I needed an explicit statement $mysqli->set_charset('utf8'); I've basically been saving all my data in some kind of odd latin1 / utf-8 mush so that if it is pulled out by my sites / latin1 shell (using latin1) it returns utf-8 data, but if it is retrieved from phpMyAdmin (utf-8 connection) it gives me those fun little characters. My fix was to pull out the data using a latin1 db connection and updating it using a utf-8 one from within PHP. Sloppy, but functional!

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 37):

Unfortunately, phpMyAdmin is one of the first php application that talk to MySQL about charset correctly. Your problem is most likely due to the fact that the database does not store the correct UTF-8 strings at first place.

In order to correctly display the characters correctly in phpMyAdmin, the data must be correctly stored in the database. However, convert the database into correct charset often breaks web apps that does not aware charset-related feature provided by MySQL.

May I ask: is MySQL > version 4.1? What web app is the database for? phpBB? Was the database migrated from an older version of the web app, or an older version of MySQL?

My suggestion is not to brother if the web app you are using is too old and not supported. Only convert database to real UTF-8 if you are sure the web app can read them correctly.

---

**Edit:**

Your MySQL is > 4.1, that means it's charset-aware. What's the charset collation settings for you database? I am pretty sure you are using `latin1`, which is MySQL name for ASCII, to store the UTF-8 text in  'bytes', into the database.

For charset-insensitive clients (i.e. mysql-cli and php-mod-mysql), characters get displayed correctly since they are being transfer to/from database as bytes. In phpMyAdmin, bytes get read and displayed as ASCII characters, that's the garbage text you seem.

Countless hours had been spend years ago (2005?) when MySQL 4.0 went obsolete, in many parts of Asia. There is a standard way to deal with your problem and gobbled data:

1. Back up your database as `.sql`
2. Open it up in UTF-8 capable text editor, make sure they look correct.
3. Look for `charset collation latin1_general_ci`, replace `latin1` to `utf8`.
4. **Save as a new sql file, do not overwrite your backup**
5. Import the new file, they will now look correctly in phpMyAdmin, and Japanese on your web app will become question marks. That's normal.
6. For your php web app that rely on php-mod-mysql, insert `mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");` after `mysql_connect()`, now the question marks will be gone.
7. Add the following configuration `my.ini` for mysql-cli:

   ```
   # CLIENT SECTION
   [mysql]
   default-character-set=utf8
   # SERVER SECTION
   [mysqld]
   default-character-set=utf8
   ```

For more information about charset on MySQL, please refer to manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html

Note that I assume your web app is using php-mod-mysql to connect to the database (hence the `mysql_connect()` function), since php-mod-mysql is the only extension I can think of that still trigger the problem TO THIS DAY.

phpMyAdmin use php-mod-mysqli to connect to MySQL. I never learned how to use it because switch to frameworks* to develop my php projects. I strongly encourage you do that too.

- Many frameworks, e.g. CodeIgniter, Zend, use mysqli or pdo to connect to databases. mod-mysql functions are considered obsolete cause performance and scalability issue. Also, you do not want to tie your project to a specific type of database.

Comment: MySQL version 5.1.41.  As I wrote, if I run a SELECT statement from the mysql command line, I see the Japanese characters correctly and see them correctly on the webpage so this is a phpMyAdmin specific issue.  The database is for my own web app that I am developing.  It is not phpBB and it has not been migrated from anything.  I am not talking about converting to UTF-8.  All the text fields have been set to UTF-8 from the beginning.

Comment: +1 The command line, especially on Windows, is not at all a reliable indicator of encoding; phpMyAdmin is actually typically right.

Comment: New answer for you. There are probably tons of articles that deal with the same thing, if you don't settle with my, Google for "SET NAMES UTF8".

Comment: Thanks for your edit Tim.  I have edited my question to provide more details.  @bobince - I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: please don't say *Unfortunately*. It's very fortunate that PHPMyAdmin does that :) +1

Comment: What if the database we're inheriting is in MySQL 3.x?  Trying to make a development environment, but can't import the database due to invalid values.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think this solution is out of date, I got "unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'" error bcz  default-character-set=utf8 is deprecated in 5.5. You should use instead:
character-set-server = utf8

Answer (score 30):

If you're using PDO don't forget to initiate it with UTF8:

```
 $con = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $server . ';dbname=' . $db . ';charset=UTF8', $user, $pass,  array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

(just spent 5 hours to figure this out, hope it will save someone precious time...)

Comment: Worked for me too, using PDO, MySQL table set to utf8_bin, Chinese characters, using XAMPP on Windows 10, luckily found this one within 5 hours.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem,

Set all text/varchar collations in phpMyAdmin to utf-8 and in php files add this:

mysql_set_charset("utf8", $your_connection_name);

This solved it for me.

Comment: ...respectively `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` for MySQLi. ;)

Answer (score 5):

the solution for this can be as easy as :

1. find the phpmysqladmin connection function/method
2. add this after database is conncted `$db_conect->set_charset('utf8');`

Answer (score 4):

Change `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_general_ci` in phpmyadmin->table_name->field_name

This is where you find it on the screen:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

phpmyadmin doesn't follow the MySQL connection because it defines its proper collation in phpmyadmin config file.

So if we don't want or if we can't access server parameters, we should just force it to send results in a different format (encoding) compatible with client i.e. phpmyadmin

for example if both the MySQL connection collation and the MySQL charset are utf8 but phpmyadmin is ISO, we should just add this one before any select query sent to the MYSQL via phpmyadmin :

```
SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =latin1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my way how do I restore the data without looseness from latin1 to utf8:

```
/**
     * Fixes the data in the database that was inserted into latin1 table using utf8 encoding.
     *
     * DO NOT execute "SET NAMES UTF8" after mysql_connect.
     * Your encoding should be the same as when you firstly inserted the data.
     * In my case I inserted all my utf8 data into LATIN1 tables.
     * The data in tables was like Ð”Ð•Ð¢Ð¡ÐšÐ˜Ð.
     * But my page presented the data correctly, without "SET NAMES UTF8" query.
     * But phpmyadmin did not present it correctly.
     * So this is hack how to convert your data to the correct UTF8 format.
     * Execute this code just ONCE!
     * Don't forget to make backup first!
     */
    public function fixIncorrectUtf8DataInsertedByLatinEncoding() {
        // mysql_query("SET NAMES LATIN1") or die(mysql_error()); #uncomment this if you already set UTF8 names somewhere

        // get all tables in the database
        $tables = array();
        $query = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
        while ($t = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
            $tables[] = $t[0];
        }
        // you need to set explicit tables if not all tables in your database are latin1 charset
        // $tables = array('mytable1', 'mytable2', 'mytable3'); # uncomment this if you want to set explicit tables

        // duplicate tables, and copy all data from the original tables to the new tables with correct encoding
        // the hack is that data retrieved in correct format using latin1 names and inserted again utf8
        foreach ($tables as $table)  {
            $temptable = $table . '_temp';
            mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $temptable LIKE $table") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $temptable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci") or die(mysql_error());
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8") or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
                $values = implode("', '", $row);
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$temptable` VALUES('$values')") or die(mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_query("SET NAMES LATIN1") or die(mysql_error());
        }

        // drop old tables and rename temporary tables
        // this actually should work, but it not, then
        // comment out this lines if this would not work for you and try to rename tables manually with phpmyadmin
        foreach ($tables as $table)  {
            $temptable = $table . '_temp';
            mysql_query("DROP TABLE `$table`") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `$temptable` RENAME `$table`") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        // now you data should be correct

        // change the database character set
        mysql_query("ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci") or die(mysql_error());

        // now you can use "SET NAMES UTF8" in your project and mysql will use corrected data
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, from the client do

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
```

This will give you something like

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_connection | latin1                     | 
| character_set_database   | latin1                     | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | latin1                     | 
| character_set_server     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

where you can inspect the general settings for the client, connection, database

Then you should also inspect the columns from which you are retrieving data with

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE TableName
```

and inspecting the charset and collation of CHAR fields (though usually people do not set them explicitly, but it is possible to give `CHAR[(length)] [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]` in `CREATE TABLE foo ADD COLUMN foo CHAR ...`)

I believe that I have listed **all** relevant settings on the side of mysql.
If still getting lost read fine [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html) and perhaps this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823278/fixing-encondings) which might shed some light (especially how I though I got it right by looking only at mysql client in the first go).

Answer (score 2):

1- Open file:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\my.ini
```

2- Look for [mysqld] entry and append:

```
character-set-server = utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

**The whole view should look like**:

```
[mysqld]
  port=3306
  character-set-server = utf8
  skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

3- Restart MySQL service!

Answer (score 2):

Its realy simple to add multilanguage in myphpadmin if you got garbdata showing in myphpadmin, just go to myphpadmin click your database go to operations tab in operation tab page see collation section set it to utf8_general_ci, after that all your garbdata will show correctly. a simple and easy trick

Answer (score 2):

The function and file names don't match those in newer versions of phpMyAdmin. Here is how to fix in the newer PHPMyAdmins:

1. Find file: 
   `phpmyadmin/libraries/DatabaseInterface.php`
2. In function: `public function query`
3. Right after the opening `{` add this:

   ```
   if($link != null){
       mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =latin1;");
       mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =latin1;");
   }
   ```

That's it. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. Database charset is utf-8 and collation is utf8_unicode_ci. I was able to see Unicode text in my webapp but the phpMyAdmin and sqldump results were garbled.

It turned out that the problem was in the way **my** web application was connecting to MySQL. I was missing the encoding flag.

After I fixed it, I was able to see Greek characters correctly in both phpMyAdmin and sqldump but **lost all my previous entries**.

Answer (score 1):

just uncomment this lines in libraries/database_interface.lib.php

```
if (! empty($GLOBALS['collation_connection'])) {
       // PMA_DBI_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';", $link, PMA_DBI_QUERY_STORE);
       //PMA_DBI_query("SET collation_connection = '" .
       //PMA_sqlAddslashes($GLOBALS['collation_connection']) . "';", $link, PMA_DBI_QUERY_STORE);
} else {
       //PMA_DBI_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';", $link, PMA_DBI_QUERY_STORE);
 }
```

if you store data in utf8 without storing charset you do not need phpmyadmin to re-convert again the connection. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution for wamp is:
    go to phpMyAdmin,
    click localhost,
    select latin1_bin for Server connection collation,
    then start to create database and table

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

below:

```
mysql_select_db(/*your_database_name*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me,

```
mysqli_query($con, "SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE `table_name` CONVERT to CHARACTER SET utf8;

*IMPORTANT: Back-up first, execute after