# Problems retrieving arabic text from the mysql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, phpmyadmin, arabic

I'm working on a project using Zend-Framework that has two languages, Arabic and English ... I have a problem with the Arabic side of the website. When I save the data (Arabic text) from the Admin side of the website, the data is successfully saved and viewed on the front end, but whenever I save the data directly on PHP-my-Admin, the data isn't properly viewed, all I get is "Question Marks".

I checked the collation for the database and made sure UTF-8 is used everywhere ... Anyone got any idea what's wrong and how to fix the problem ??

Thanks

Comment: Question possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: salam Naruto , could you please provide me with yout collation of your database tables , so i can guide you throug it convert all text to fine arabic in both phpmyadmin + your add and please tell me if you don't use zend db ..

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that data is saved correctly in DB?
Are these/such lines in your config file?:

```
db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
db.params.charset = utf8
```

Comment: Yes. in database config file change your charset to UTF8