# Wrong letters after adding strings into database Python

Tags: python, mysql, text

after adding about 6k of lines into my mySQL database through Python, some letters are wrong ( polish letters), like Å‚ for ł and Å¼ for ż and others. How can I repair that? My python code is:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb
import string
import codecs
file = codecs.open("----", 'r', 'utf-8')
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="-----", port=3306, user="-----", passwd="------", db="----")
cursor = db.cursor()
for line in file:
        lines = string.replace(line, "'", '"')
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Logs (Text) VALUE ('%s')"% lines.encode("utf-8"))
db.close()
print("done")
```

and after running this code, it works normally , but in PhpMyAdmin, there is wrong letters.
Coding in Database is UTF-8, file is in ANSI as UTF-8 (from notepad++).
Any Help?

Comment: Are you sure PHPMyAdmin isn't just displaying it wrong? You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: It's displaying correctly, the answer down here is making it working.

Comment: use parameterized sql instead of Python string interpolation

Comment: Instead of `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Logs (Text) VALUE ('%s')"% lines.encode("utf-8"))`, better do `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Logs (Text) VALUE (%s)", lines.encode("utf-8"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the charset in `MySQLdb.connect()`:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="-----", port=3306, user="-----",
    passwd="------", db="----", charset='utf8')
```

Comment: Small change, utf8 without "-" and works, thanks, i'll add this as accepted answer after few minutes