# How to properly save non english character into MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, character

I am working on parsing a HTML of website and saving information to database but in the website, there are Non English character (like Chinese, Indian, Korean, etc) that should be saved into MySQL. My problem is that in MySQL (when i view those information using PHP MyAdmin), it displays weird characters.

> Ä°lginÃ§ GerÃ§ekler
>   ê³µì—°ì •ë³´ PARTI(ì—°ê·¹,ì½˜ì„œíŠ¸,ë®¤ì§€ì»¬,ì˜¤í...
>   ì •ì‹  ì—°ë ¹ í…ŒìŠ¤íŠ¸

How to properly save these information to database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

after mysql_connect or mysql_select_db. I use that for Turkish
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'latin5'");

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that the Table and Row Encoding is UTF-8 Formated.
Next you should save the PHP Script file as UTF-8 Encoded With or Without BOM.

Or you can try using [htmlspecialchars();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your insertion and/or tables to another coding style. Here you are how: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Answer (score 0):

change your table collation to utf8

```
$con=mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8",$con);
```

check also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)