# PHP insert to MySQL attachments in base 64 format

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I try save to database attachments in base64 format

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `attachments`(mp_id, at_source, at_format)
                        VALUES(".$id.", '".$attach['data']."', '".$attach['mimetype']."'  )
                ";
```

Gettings error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '€čH•zøŻU…   ¨@' at line 2

I think something is wriong with `''` quotes , how to insert base64 encoded file source ?

I'm add attachment: http://pastebin.com/srYbHTAS

Comment: what is the type of field that you are saving the base64 format value ?

Comment: you may have to use blob data type

Comment: can you show how you encoded to base64 format ?

Comment: I parser emails from Gmail IMAP, I not need to encode.

Comment: I'm add attachemnt to pastebin, see it

Comment: please  take look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345892/how-to-properly-save-non-english-character-into-mysql-database-using-php). it might help you

Comment: @krishna I get error when INSERTING

Comment: you are trying to save non-english alphabets, so you need to set to appropriate language to detect non-english alphabets

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not base64 encoded. You try to insert the raw attachment data.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `attachments`(mp_id, at_source, at_format)
                        VALUES(".$id.", '".base64_encode($attach['data'])."', '".$attach['mimetype']."'  )";
```

Base64 looks like something like this:

> TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCBieSB0aGlz
>   IHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbmltYWxzLCB3aGljaCBpcyBhIGx1c3Qgb2Yg
>   dGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2Ugb2YgZGVsaWdodCBpbiB0aGUgY29udGlu
>   dWVkIGFuZCBpbmRlZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXRpb24gb2Yga25vd2xlZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRo
>   ZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=