# Mysql + PHP Search word without utf8

Tags: php, mysql, search

I get problem with mysql search LIKE
For example in database table city i have record "Rīga" 
How you see in database Word "Rīga" have "ī" not "i" letter. 
Is it posibble to make in search even if i write with regular "i" letter?
Because this variant isnt working

```
SELECT * FROM `city` WHERE `title` LIKE '%Riga%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called *Accent insensitive search*: you can find a good answer right here! [Accent insensitive search query in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647080/accent-insensitive-search-query-in-mysql)

Other answers:

- [How do I perform an accent insensitive compare (e with è, é, ê and ë) in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-%C3%A8-%C3%A9-%C3%AA-and-%C3%AB-in-sql-ser)
- [How to MySQL work "case insensitive" and "accent insensitive" in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831076/how-to-mysql-work-case-insensitive-and-accent-insensitive-in-utf-8)

Comment: Yes finally i did , thank you :)
`$q1 = mq($db2, "SELECT * FROM city WHERE title LIKE _utf8'%ka%' collate utf8_general_ci");` This fixed everything :)

Comment: sorry for double post but i get another problem. If i write ka its work but if i write more than 2 letters its shows nothing, for example "kar" its shows nothing but when "ka" its shows 2 records, why is that?

Comment: I must say it's pretty strange. I don't have a final answer to this behavior: maybe because the letter with strange accent is not the last one? Try something like `%ka%r%` and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same connection encoding as your database before executing queries.

If you're using **PDO**, just set the connection encoding as:

```
$encoding = "utf8"; //replace this value with the character encoding you're using
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=my_db;charset=$encoding", $user, $pass);
```

If you're using **MYSQLI**, use `mysqli_set_charset`:

```
$encoding = "utf8"; //Use your encode here
$con = mysqli_connect("host",$user,$pass,"my_db");
mysqli_set_charset($con, $encoding);
```

---

**Edit~**

You may need also to use Accent insensitive collation (*UTF8_GENERAL_CI*) in your database.
I believe your problem is already solved in the post [MySQL charsets and collations: accent insensitive doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362082/mysql-charsets-and-collations-accent-insensitive-doesnt-work)

Comment: Nop its not working. Maybe i didn't explain well. I want make a system whats similar google search. For example in database have 2 records
Kārsava
and
Kandava
If i make search "SELECT * FROM `city` WHERE `title` LIKE '%ka%'"; its return only Kandava but i want that if he returns Kārsava too. I tried your solution but didnt work

Comment: Updated. Thanks to the references @Sylter 's answer, but using mysql :)