# phpMyAdmin Export Issues with Chinese Characters

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having some issues with the phpMyAdmin Export feature when it comes to foreign characters (most notably Chinese.)  The default charset is `UTF-8`.  When I browse the rows through phpMyAdmin, the characters are correct.  I'm inserting the data into MySQL through PHP using a `UTF-8` charset.

All seems to be well.  I only get the wrong output when I use phpMyAdmin to perform an export, whether it be CSV, .sql, JSON, whatever.  Viewing the exported files in a simple text editor with `UTF-8` encoding seems to result the same as well, so I'm guessing this could be due to my phpMyAdmin export configuration?  Has anyone else ever experienced this?

```
真棒男人酷   真棒男人酷
```

is becoming

```
çœŸæ£’ç”·äººé…· çœŸæ£’ç”·äººé…·
```

Many thanks, SO

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: NO... the question you mentioned that could be a possible duplicate is related to VIEWING in phpmyadmin.  My question pertains to EXPORTING various formats in phpmyadmin.  The DA you're suggesting says that the characters do not show up correctly while viewing, where as mine do.  Different problems.  This shouldn't be downvoted or flagged for closing.