# export accents wrong phpmyadmin

Tags: database, unicode, phpmyadmin

I have a big problem into my server.
I have to export a database, but when I try and import it accent are wrong.
For example I hava table with collation latin1_swedish_ci and a row into the old database like this:

```
Das Nationale Transplantation âCentrum
```

I export the table from my phpmyadmin because I don't have access to the ssh of this server.
The export is .sql with compatibility mode:NONE

I create the table into new server in latin1_swedish_ci and try to import the sql the record now is this:

```
Das Nationale Transplantation â??Centrum
```

How can I export my table without lost this accent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export, click on Custom and choose which character set you want to use for your file. When you import back, do the same in the Import dialog.

Also, maybe you data is wrongly stored from the beginning. See http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data.

Comment: If you have a look at your .sql file, is the accented character correct at this point?