# incorrect output 4 bytes symbols in mysql table with utf8mb4 encode

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to insert via phpmyadmin 4 bytes character in the tabel. (phpmyadmin version is 5.5.33).

1. I assigned Server connection collation to utf8mb4_general_ci collation;
2. Database has utf8mb4 encode;
3. Table and column has utf8mb4 encode;

I tryed to insert  symbol and it was success and without any errors! But this symbol in the table is displayed as ????.
Can someone help, please?

Comment: which client are you using? Is it in the same collation/encode? because if isn't it won't show you your character.

Comment: Variable character_set_client = 'utf8'. But query "SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4'" does not change it.

Comment: and which client is that ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Client is php.

Comment: You mean a code that read the table and print the output or a web administration tool made in php like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Wich one? the code or the tool ?

Comment: php administration tool.

Answer (score 0):

So I would reccomend you to check what is the application web encoding  because your problem is not the data itself is the program that is printing it. If your php administration tool or the web container (apache most probably) that is hosting this application doesn't have your character encoding you wont see your character. Most of theese application use just UTF8 as encoding therefore I suggest you to change your database to this encoding just UTF8 and the collation to utf8_general_ci.

Your question is most probably related with this one [How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)