# phpmyadmin displaying weird chars (utf8)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin

So I have set mysql for full utf8 support:

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
character_set_client=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
```

and

```
mysql> show variables like "char%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like "coll%";
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I correctly store and get (and json_encode) utf8 characters in my web app with my mysql queries but I have a problem with phpmyadmin. The problem is that phpmyadmin displays those international characters as garbled text.

```
Î­Î»ÎµÎ¿Ï‚

sadaa
```

just to clarify things out, I'm talking about NEW DATA, not already stored data which may be corrupted.

the session variables for phpmyadmin are:

```
show variables like "char%";
Variable_name   Value   
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/

show variables like "coll%" 
Variable_name   Value   
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_general_ci
collation_server    utf8_general_ci
```

The only way I have found till now for the international utf8 characters to display properly in phpmyadmin and not as garbled text is to run

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

every time before a client app (php) query which:
a) is weird because as you can see everything is properly utf8
b) i would like to avoid running that query every time

is this a phpmyadmin only problem or a general data encoding problem with my settings? Either way, how can I solve this? Preferrably just with configuration files settings, not having to run the SET NAMES utf8 query each time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [_How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin).

Comment: You're omitting the most important bits: your *table* collation and your actual *client* encoding. Everything else are nothing but default values. If you've been inserting data from PHP without `SET NAMES utf8` (though that's not the recommended way to do it), it's probably corrupted by now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario you are right. I was not setting in my app the connection charset. I believe I have solved it now. Posted an answer of my own down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It seems it was not a phpmyadmin problem but a general encoding problem.

The problem was I was not setting my client connection charset.

here's what I got if I displayed the variables from a php file:

```
{"Variable_name":"character_set_client","Value":"latin1"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_connection","Value":"latin1"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_database","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_filesystem","Value":"binary"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_results","Value":"latin1"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_server","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_system","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_sets_dir","Value":"\/usr\/share\/mysql\/charsets\/"}



{"Variable_name":"collation_connection","Value":"latin1_swedish_ci"}
{"Variable_name":"collation_database","Value":"utf8_general_ci"}
{"Variable_name":"collation_server","Value":"utf8_general_ci"}
```

Initially i tried adding in my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

IT DOES NOT WORK.

so the solution was to add:

```
charset=UTF8
```

in the PDO initialization

so after that I got the proper variable values:

```
{"Variable_name":"character_set_client","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_connection","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_database","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_filesystem","Value":"binary"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_results","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_server","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_set_system","Value":"utf8"}
{"Variable_name":"character_sets_dir","Value":"\/usr\/share\/mysql\/charsets\/"}



{"Variable_name":"collation_connection","Value":"utf8_general_ci"}
{"Variable_name":"collation_database","Value":"utf8_general_ci"}
{"Variable_name":"collation_server","Value":"utf8_general_ci"}
```