# Urdu / Arabic font data from MySQL is displaying as ????? in JSON

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8, urdu

I am developing an Android app with Urdu/Arabic data store in MySQL database on my web server and using JSON_Encoding to generate the JSON string. The JSON string is then being used in Android app to perform various functions (populating RecyclerView and other view objects with data). I am able to store Urdu / Arabic data in MySQL database, but when I use PHP script to generate JSON, all the fields containing Urdu characters is displaying data as ??????

I was using the utf8mb4_unicode_ci as I read the this is easy for storing non-English data and performing multiple functions, but after this encoding problem, I have changed that to utf8_general_ci for all the tables and fields in MySQL database. Below is the PHP script I am using to generate the JSON string from MySQL:

```
<?php

require "conn.php";

mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysqli_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 

$sql_qry = "SELECT * FROM countrybasic;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_qry);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($response, array("id"=>$row[0],"name"=>$row[1],"capital"=>$row[2],"continent"=>$row[3],"population"=>$row[4],"gdp"=>$row[5]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The Name and Capital fields are the ones I store my Urdu data in.

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: No sir, still the same. Text is displaying as ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the Charset to UTF8, and you can use these lines for PHP to do it:

```
$statSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($your_db,$sSQL) 
or die ('charset in DB didn\'t change');
```

I hope this help :)

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to set charset for query and fields. Never occured to me to set it for Connection object as well. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: I'm glad that help...  Don't forget to market it as an answer :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your table [countrybasic] with collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci and make the name column with the same colation.
2. Now insert some sample data in different languages.
3. Get the data using MySQLi query result.

Note: If you save the data when the collation is different and get that one after changing the collation then that data will not fetch correctly.

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$CONNECTION = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
   mysqli_query ($CONNECTION ,"set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
$queryutf8 = "select * from yourtable";
$res_utf8  = mysqli_query($CONNECTION ,$queryutf8 );
```

Comment: i already check this code it is running and get a row content

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the default utf8 in the wamp server
check the below link for more detail.

[Arabic characters doesn't show in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366741/arabic-characters-doesnt-show-in-phpmyadmin/67621383#67621383)