# phpmyadmin shows rubbish when browsing arabic contents on tables

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I tried so much to find the solution for this problem, I think the problem on phpmyadmin itself.
I set true collaction value "utf8_general_ci" and tried also "utf16_general_ci".
configure mysql character system set also, but the problem is still.

FYI, when I retrieve the data from the table using php code the data would be on arabic and intact, but from phpmyadmin there was rubbish like :Ø§Ø³Ù…Ù‡
Ø±Ù‚Ù…Ù‡
Ø§Ø³ØªØ§Ø° Ù…Ø³Ø§Ø¹Ø"

Comment: Is the data in the database stored as UTF-8 or as win-1256?

Comment: I dunno why OP's being downvoted, this is a legit question.

Comment: This is a legit question indeed. Downvoters please explain.

Comment: I think that what @Tarik is asking is, which locale did you use when you filled the database in? This is usually accomplished with a `SET NAMES` query.

Comment: @Tarik is stored as UTF-8.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/4779380/2385479 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26436561/2385479 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/21279793/2385479 and https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data ? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Can you show some code about when you set up the database connection?