# Data in Non-English script being displayed as "??" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, encoding

I have Movie Titles in Non-English scripts like Hindi, Korean, Japanese which are stored in my MySQL database. However when I do a select query on the table the titles are being displayed as `"??"`. Any pointers what might be going wrong?

I checked the Encoding for the database using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character\_set\_database";` and it comes to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code while you are connection with server. May be it can help you.

```
$con=mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8",$con);
```

And check also [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin) and this [article](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data).