# How to sort right to left language data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database that is storing Persian data and information. 
the information are names and I want to sort names by alphabet. but MySQL don't know Persian language, and some other right to left languages.

**How can I sort them?**

and my other problem is with phpmyAdmin, phpmyAdmin can't show Persian language data and show some character instead of that

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Did you have a look into collations? Google that...

Comment: @SidM I don't know how to do it, and its a long time that I am working with mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the first question; as fancyPants said, use the proper collation and you should be fine. Sorting is handled by collations and there is a utf8 Persian collation available.

About your second problem:

Almost certainly what is happening is that you're improperly storing the data. As Sid M said, knowing what you've tried and how your system is running would be a big help, but these questions almost always end up being misconfigured or poorly written software. phpMyAdmin and MySQL can deal just fine with multiple character sets. Presumably, you'll want to use utf8.

Set up your database and tables properly, then make sure your client application is configured properly (likely using `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` or `mysql_set_charset('utf8')`, but read the links for more detail than is worth including here).

See https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data and [How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin) for starters and [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602) for way more information than you probably wanted to learn :)