# phpmyadmin/mysql format a column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Am stuck at a little problem. I have a MySQL database with 4 columns. I have a customer_name column which assumes all the text in it should me customers name. But someone some customer names mix up with some numerical text and some unreadable characters. So can you suggest me the easy way to format the column by replacing the numerical text and undesirable characters.

Eg:

## Current Column:

User123
user12user
123usernew
 A$Ã˜Â¡Ã™â€ Ã˜Â´Ã™â€ Ã˜Â§userold

## Expected Output:

User
useruser
usernew
userold

I hope you guys got what am trying to say, any help is appreciated. The column is of nearly 1000K Values in it. so importing or recreating is a bit risk for me.

Comment: Do you need to just batch process your current table, or establish a routine for sanitizing customer names down the road?

Comment: This may help you [How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: @JeremyCarlson, Both. I want to process the current table and also add a new routine for filling column with name only and no undesirable characters in future.

Comment: @Rafiq thanks for the garbage text cleaning solution.