# Character encoding not supporting Polish characters in MySQL/PHPmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have an MySQL database that has some Polish characters in it showing as `?` instead of letters like "ł, ą, ć, etc". 
I have changed the collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` and `utf8_polish_ci`.

I have also tried this on the table

`ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN txt TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8`

and still nothing.

My table still looks like this:

[image]

Maybe someone knows why?

Comment: What is the mysql server charset? The connection charset? What is the apache default charset too? Note that the chars in the database can be broken before you change the colation. In this case you need to convert them.

Comment: Are you sure that you have good data in mysql table? It seems you have broken data stored.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a factor of how you're inserting data. Answers to the questions @bski wrote would be helpful here. What application is inserting the data? What charset is being used for that connection?

Most likely you haven't set the charset in your application, or have set it incorrectly. Issue a command like `SET NAMES 'UTF8';` when initializing the connection and see if that improves the data stored.

phpMyAdmin itself works fine with UTF data and pretty much displays exactly what is stored in the MySQL database, so in cases like this when the data doesn't appear correct it means your application isn't storing it correctly. If it appears correct in your application, it basically means you're both inserting and retrieving it incorrectly.

Related links:

- http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data (also includes helpful information on fixing existing bad data)
- [How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

there 2 possibility

1) your column not alter correctly. use below query.

ALTER TABLE  `miasta` CHANGE  `nazwa_miasta`  `nazwa_miasta` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL

2) check string at time of insert. if during insert the string is not in utf8 it create problem. so first convert it in utf8 ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php ) then insert.