# phpMyAdmin won't display or insert Unicode characters properly into database

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin version 4.4.4 with MySQL 5.6 (charset is set to UTF-8 Unicode). The table in question has the collation set to `utf8-general-ci` and all fields are also set to `utf8-general-ci` collation as well. My php.ini file has `default_charset = "UTF-8"`.

Despite all the UTF-8 settings for all three applications, unicode characters appear garbled when viewing a table within phpMyAdmin. So, instead of seeing ...

```
Søren
```

... in phpMyAdmin I see ...

```
SÃ¸ren
```

Even though it displays garbled in phpMyAdmin, it displays correctly on the website. The only problem is with phpMyAdmin.

If I attempt to Insert a new record using phpMyAdmin and enter `Søren` in a text field, it displays like this within phpMyAdmin...

```
Søren
```

Which looks correct there, but, on the web page, it displays like this...

```
S�ren
```

The ø character is replaced with a question mark inside a black diamond instead of displaying the proper unicode character on the website.

What the heck is going on? How do I make phpMyAdmin display and insert the unicode characters properly into the table without mangling them? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: @Fabricator Are you referring to the selected answer? I have no file called /libraries/dbi/mysqli.dbi.lib.php in my phpMyAdmin install.

Comment: what about the other answers with higher score?

Answer (score 1):

> My php.ini file has default_charset = "UTF-8".

That only affects the charset used for some PHP built-in functions like `htmlentities`.

MySQL uses its own charset to decode stuff you send it. This can be set using `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` for mysqli, or `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` for the deprecated mysql module, or using `charset=utf8` in the connection string in PDO.