# JDBC Greek characters

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have problems when inserting a record into the database that includes greek characters.Even though the database default characters set is utf8 and I also added the parameters in the connection URL I get ????? characters instead of the actual greek characters.

```
public class Queries 
{
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Ezazel";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

    private Connection connection = null;
    private PreparedStatement insertSight = null;
    private PreparedStatement insertHotel = null;
public Queries()
    {
        try 
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection( URL,USERNAME, PASSWORD );         
            insertSight = connection.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO Sights ( Title, Description, Address, Latitude, Longitude ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
            insertHotel = connection.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO Hotels ( Title, Description, Address, Latitude, Longitude ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )" );
        } 
        catch ( SQLException e ) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit( 1 );
        }
    }

    public void addSight( String title, String description, String address, double latitude, double longitude )
    {
        try 
        {
            insertSight.setString( 1, title );
            insertSight.setString( 2, description );
            insertSight.setString( 3, address );
            insertSight.setDouble( 4, latitude );
            insertSight.setDouble( 5, longitude );

            insertSight.executeUpdate();        
        } 
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try 
            {
                insertSight.close();
                connection.close();
            } 
            catch ( SQLException e )
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit( 1 );
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying utf-8 in your connection string,

```
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Ezazel?characterEncoding=utf8";
```

Also, where do you see  ????? characters ?  Viewer needs to support UTF - 8 if you meant that.

If data is successfully being saved in Greek but only a visibility issue of phpMyAdmin  , try to to verify if collation and charset are set to UTF-8

[How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)