# MYSQL replies differently for similar queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using xamp server:

when I am running the select query to get data as

```
SELECT `id`, `relation`, `member_id`, `Relative_id` 
    FROM `relationship` WHERE `relation` = 'माँ'
```

All works fine

But when running below example of queries I get 0 results.

Example 1 :

```
SELECT `id`, `relation`, `member_id`, `Relative_id` 
    FROM `relationship` WHERE `relation` = 'बेटी'
```

Example 2 :

```
SELECT `id`, `relation`, `member_id`, `Relative_id` 
    FROM `relationship` WHERE `relation` = 'पिता'
```

the image regarding db table

[image: click here]
Table structure:[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGeOq.png)

Comment: Seems like encoding problem

Comment: Agreed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698282/57191 might help

Comment: I mean,you are using different filters as what you wrote in Hindi is first daughter, then mother, then husband. What do you expect then? you are giving different filter parameters. I cant imagine anyone being a daughter, mother and husband all in one person, not even in India.

Comment: 'member_id' is for a person but the 'relative_id' for his different relatives and the 'relation' is how member related with that specific relative

Comment: what character set are you using in your db?   Where are you calling these queries from?  Is this behavior replicated when you run the queries in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I am using utf8 as character set.  I am calling this queries in  php . and when I use phpmyadmin same behavior

Answer (score 2):

You must use a Unicode character set (utf8_unicode_ci works fine), declare the field as `VARCHAR` and use `LIKE`, instead of `=`

```
SELECT `id`, `relation`, `member_id`, `Relative_id` 
FROM `relationship` WHERE `relation` LIKE 'पिता';
```

Tested and working.

Comment: changing character set to  'utf8_unicode_ci' works fine, even ' = ' also works

Comment: @AJAYRAGHUVANSHI welcome to SO.  If any of the answers on this post solves your problem, it is usual to award it as `correct answer`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `UTF-8` encoding to compare language.

Use [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: I used mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8"); in my php code but no effect

Comment: could you share your table structure as well ?