# UTF-8 Caracters don't display correctly in database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a database in PhpMyAdmin where it's caracter set is UTF-8 which doesn't display correctly (it contains weird symbols).

I tried following this solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/741864/how-to-display-text-in-utf8-from-mysql-phpmyadmin) , but I still have the same problem.
Also I tried this solution too: [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin) but this didn't work .
The last thing I did is export the database in to an SQL file then changing it with Notpad++ to encode UTF-8 and then importing this SQL file in to the database again, but nothing changed; the gebberish characters still exist.

I am using:

- PhpMyAdmin ( wamp server version : 5.7.24 - MySQL)
- Database caracter set : UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
- The colloation proprety in PhpMyAdmin : `utf8_general_ci`
- When I insert values in database like words in french (" é ") it works, but the old existing values returns just symbols and weird things like `contr├┤le`
- My application is coded using PHP and I start every connection to database with :

  ```
  $db->exec("set names utf8");
  ```

I hope someone can guide me to how to solve this probelm I will appreciate it very much .

Comment: What is the current table definition (ie the collation property) ? What happens when you edit data using phpMyAdmin ? Does it save the data consistently ? Then it could be your application that is not sending proper UTF8-encoded data. 
Consider posting some more code.

Comment: @Anonymous I added some more details in the post. The probelm exists only with the data already existing  in the database , but the new data when I try inserting them they are inserted correctly.

Comment: Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) will almost certainly solve your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I still have the same problem . I coudnt figure it out