# Unicode characters do not display correctly in phpMyAdmin GUI

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, phpmyadmin

***Note:** This is not a duplicate of the related question, since it does not answer/solve my problem: [How to display UTF-8 characters in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777900/how-to-display-utf-8-characters-in-phpmyadmin)*

---

I have a database containing Unicode characters, including Japanese and Arabic. These characters are not displayed correctly in the *phpMyAdmin* GUI in the browser (via `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`) and they appear as mojibake, e.g. `ã‚«ã‚º`.

On the other hand, when connecting to the database and retrieving data from it using PHP PDO, the Unicode characters are all shown correctly, even without setting `SET NAMES 'utf8'` or adding `charset=utf8` in `new PDO(…)`.

---

Here is everything I have tried so far after extensive research, but without success:

I have already set the collation of the database/tables to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` before creating the tables and checked the collation again via “Operations” → “Table options” → “Collation”.

I have also tried executing `ALTER TABLE xxx CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;` on the tables in question to ensure the character set is correct, however, this does not seem to solve the in-browser issue.

When creating the tables, I made sure to use `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`, but this still does not fix the incorrect encoding.

I even checked the `<meta>` tag through the web inspector, and it is correctly set to `charset="utf-8"`.

In `config.inc.php`, I set `DefaultCharset` to `'utf8mb4'` and in `my.ini`, I included `collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci` and `character-set-server=utf8` under `[mysqld]` as well as `default-character-set=utf8` under `[client]`, which too does not make any difference.

Also, I set “Server connection collation” on the front page of the *phpMyAdmin* GUI to `utf8_unicode_520_ci` to match the collation of the tables.

Taking this into consideration, I conclude that the character set/collation of the table is most likely not the problem in itself.

---

I know I could fix the incorrectly encoded strings by executing the SQL commands from the PHP script or the using `mb_convert_encoding($str, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8")` (which yields Japanese `カズ` for `$str = "ã‚«ã‚º"`), but this would be quite time-consuming compared to executing the commands in-browser.

---

**Why are Unicode strings not shown correctly in the GUI and how can I solve this issue?** Strings show perfectly fine running the PHP script (which is why this question is *not* code-specific).

Comment: See Mojibake in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  Do not use any PHP conversion functions; that will just confuse things more.

Comment: @RickJames Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246806/rick-james-lypyrhythm).