# MySQL Replace() function doesn't give a correct output for non-latin characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, replace

In the MySQL documentation the string function `REPLACE()` is said to be "multi-byte safe". I have problems working with my Russian charset.

```
    SELECT REPLACE('оофо', 'о', '*'); -- "**ф*", everything is correct
    SELECT REPLACE('оофоо', 'о', '*'); -- "**фоо", NOT CORRECT
```

Where should I look for the source of the problem?

Additional information:

> ```
> OS - Windows 7 (Russian),
> SELECT CHARSET('оофоо'); -- "utf8",
> SELECT LENGTH('оофоо'); -- "6".
> ```

Comment: `SELECT LENGTH('оофоо')` returns **10** for me, and your both `REPLACE` calls return the right result.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the database charset/coallition is UTF-8
2. On the page you insert these russian characters ( the form, textarea
       ), make sure the encoding is UTF-8, by setting `Content-Type to
       text/html; charset=utf-8`. Enter in Russian text directly to the form
       input.
3. On the processing page that handles this form, which inserts it into
       the database, make sure to do `SET NAMES utf8` so it's stored as UTF-8
       **before** you insert the data, in a separate query beforehand.
4. When you render the content from the database in a view, make sure
       the `Content-Type is text/html; charset=utf-8`.
5. Make sure that the content-type is **not** windows-1251 or
       iso-8859-1/latin1. Make sure the database charset/coallition is NOT
       ISO-8859-1/Latin1.

---

Refer to, for further information: [Fixing encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823278/fixing-encodings)

Comment: I use the MySQL database from the Windows console, not from a web page.